# find the index in a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

it's a basic problem that given a sorted array and a target value, find the index if the target is found. If not, return the index where it would be if it were inserted in order.
Here is my method:

```
public int searchInsert1(int[] A, int target) {
    if (A == null || A.length == 0)
        return 0;
    return search(A, target, 0, A.length);
}
public int search(int[] a, int target, int s, int e) {
    if (s == e)
        return s;
    int mid = (s + e) / 2;
    if (a[mid] == target) {
        return mid;
    } else if (target < a[mid]) {
        return search(a, target, 0, mid - 1);
    } else {
        return search(a, target, mid, e);
    }
}
```

somehow, it always returns the wrong index value. However, if I change the `if else` part as the following, it works:

```
    if (a[mid] == target) {
        return mid;
    } else if (target > a[mid]) {
        return search(a, target, mid + 1, e);
    } else {
        return search(a, target, 0, mid);
    }
```

can anyone help me with it in detail? Thanks so much in advance

Comment: *"...find the index if the target is found. If not, return the index where it would be if it were inserted in order..." Then how would you know whether it was found?

Comment: What's your actual question? You have working code, apparently. If you're wondering why it works and the other doesn't, surely you can figure that out from your debugger? Is that the question?

Comment: It seems obvious -- in the first version, if `target` is smaller than the middle value you search the upper half of the array.  Obviously, if `target` is smaller than the middle value, and the array is sorted in ascending order, you want to search the lower half of the array.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `Arrays.binarySearch` methods?

Comment: You start by calling the method with 0 and length as arguments. So the `e` argument is the upper limit, excluded. But then when t`arget < a[mid]` you call search with `a[mid - 1]` as the upper limit, instead of `a[mid]`. `a[mid - 1]` could be the searched value, but you're excluding it.

Comment: There are two off-by-1 errors: In the first case it has to be `mid` instead of `mid - 1`. In the second case, it has to be `mid + 1` instead of `mid`, in oder to avoid an endless recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has errors in these parts:
1. you have set end index wrong, it should be :A.length - 1;
2. your return value in the condition part is wrong,the return value in your "else" part should be: search(a, target, 0, mid+1, e);

Correct code should be:

```
    public int searchInsert1(int[] A, int target) {
        if (A == null || A.length == 0)
            return 0;

        // check if target is larger than the largest value or smaller than the smallest value
        if (target < A[0])
            return 0;
        else if (target > A[A.length-1])
            return A.length-1;

        return search(A, target, 0, A.length-1);
    }

    public int search(int[] a, int target, int s, int e) {
        if (s == e)
            return s;
        int mid = (s + e) / 2;
        if (a[mid] == target) {
            return mid;
        } else if (target < a[mid]) {
            return search(a, target, 0, mid - 1);
        } else {
            return search(a, target, mid+1, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @nosid  the return value is 1, it's correct. what's the problem?

Comment: @nosidthe index of an array starts from 0

Comment: Sorry, wrong example. Search for `0` in `{ 1, 2 }`.

Comment: @nosid: you are right. I should fix the boundary scenarios. Now fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
 public int search(int[] a, int target, int s, int e) {
     int low = s;
     int high = e- 1;

     while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        int midVal = a[mid];

        if (midVal < target)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (midVal > target)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid; // key found
     }
     return -(low + 1);  // key not found.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simplest solution in **Java**

```
public static int search(int[] a, int target) {

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        if (a[i] == target) {

            return i;

        }


    }
    return -1;
}
```